# SSH into a machine and then launch an interactive command line program

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I would like to actually ssh into a machine (not remotely execute a command like `ssh -i key.pem user@host 'bash -s' < script.sh`) and *then* once that is complete run a command to launch an interactive command line program on the remote machine. Any ideas? Note all of this is done in a script and the end result should be a interactive command line program running *within* the shell on the remote host.

So far I have tried in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

```
import os
os.system("xterm -e ssh -tt -i key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip_address yRouter/src/yrouter --interactive=1 user")
```

But the `xterm` session closes immediately after. The "yrouter" is the executable on the remote machine and `--interactive=1 user` are its arguments.

To clarify: the result after running the Python code above should be an `xterm` (or any terminal window) open, already sshed into the remote host AND have the interactive command line program `yrouter` running.

Comment: `ssh -i key.pem user@host` should give you an interactive login shell session after login...

Comment: Once what is complete?

Comment: after the interactive shell session begins

Comment: @heemayl ya after the interactive login shell begins, I would like to run another (different) interactive command line program on the remote host

Comment: Just run `bash` (or whatever shell you want) after login and you are good..

Comment: Nope not bash ... a different program which exists on the remote machine

Comment: I am doing this from a script, that is the problem

Comment: Now i see..does `ssh -tt -i key.pem user@host 'bash -s' <script.sh` help?

Comment: No still doesn't work

Comment: Then you should edit your question to add the contents of `script.sh` and also show whats your target and where it is failing..

Comment: Once you ssh into a machine, any program you run is executed on the remote machine.  If you want to run a GUI program, you can use `ssh -X` (or `Y`); note that is uppercase for both.  The remote machine needs to have X-windows running to run an X-windows app, but that's it.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Its not a GUI, it is a interactive command line program (like bash). Basically I would like to run that python code and then end up with a xterm (or another other terminal window) open, sshed into the remote host and have that command line program running.

Comment: There is possibly a problem with `yRouter/src/yrouter --interactive=1 user`..have a test, replace `yRouter/src/yrouter --interactive=1 user` with `bash -i`..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you pass a command in the arguments `ssh` runs non-interactively;

```
$ ssh -t user@localhost echo foo
user@localhost's password: 
foo
Connection to localhost closed.
```

A solution is to replace the non-interactive shell with an interactive shell in the command passed to `ssh`:

```
$ ssh -t user@localhost 'echo foo; exec zsh'
user@localhost's password: 
foo
%
```

In your case, to replace the non-interactive shell e.g. with an interactive Bash instance:

```py
import os
os.system("xterm -e ssh -tt -i key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip_address 'yRouter/src/yrouter --interactive=1 user; exec bash'")
```

Comment: kos, even running non-interactively, until the command returns `yRouter/src/yrouter --interactive=1 user` (in this case), the session will be active while using `-t`..

Comment: As OP has marked it as accepted, perhaps i have misunderstood the question..

Comment: @heemayl Not really sure what you mean, but kos's answer works. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Bear with me @heemayl but I'm not getting exactly what you mean with "active", you mean "interactive"?

Comment: @CheckMateNinja No problem, glad that it helped.

Comment: @CheckMateNinja Just a suggestion for you, start using `subprocess` module instead of deprecated and insecure `os.system` to run native shell commands..

Comment: I meant the session will be ongoing until the command returns i.e. the command will be running..no?

Comment: @heemayl Yes, AFAIU it goes like this (->=runs): `ssh` -> non-interactive shell -> `command`; so if `command` is actually `command1; command2` and `command2` is `exec X`, `command2` replaces the non interactive shell, which will cease anyway after `command2`, but being `command2` now a interactive shell that shell must be exited manually

Comment: thats what i meant..so if the first command of OP is itself running, the session will not be closed..i thought OP is trying and failing to run the command rather than opening a shell session later on..now the question seems ambiguous to me..anyway, +1 for you..

Comment: @heemayl Thanks :) Ah I see, no, I think you missed this edit: "But the xterm session closes immediately after.". That was what gave it out to me